# Keyup function into form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script I am using to copy a field into another input field using `keyup blur paste`. This script works, however I need to modify it to also go into two different form elements which are named `data-cost=""` and `debt=""`, instead of the `<div id="viewer">`

This is the script as I have it now :

```
$(function () {
    $('#account_balance1').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var str = $(self).val();
            $("#viewer").text(str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
        }, 0);
    });

    $("#viewer").text($('#Website').val().replace(/^\$/, ''));
});
```

This is the html :

```
<!--This where I get the value from -->
<input type="text" class="balance" id="account_balance1" name="cardb" value=""/>

<!--the first 2 elements are where I need the values to go -->
<input data-cost="" debt="" value="" type="checkbox" name="f_2[]"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need the two attributes (data-cost and debt) to be each set to your value you need:

```
$("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('data-cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
$("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
```

Comment: are you saying to put them both under `var str = $(self).val();` and replace `$("#viewer").text(str.replace(/^http\:\/\//, ''));`

Comment: yep, sorry didnt see your question ealier, but that is exactly what i meant.  Glad it worked for ya!

Comment: You seem to know your stuff, so if you interested I am asking question related to this and since you know this, you might be able to answer this easily if you are looking to build up points.

Answer (score 0):

Just use that selector then

```
$("input[data-cost][data-debt]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're maybe having a fundamental misunderstanding of what the data attributes are for? You're aware that they will not be posted with the form? I think what you're looking for is the data function which will allow you to set the data attributes http://api.jquery.com/data/.

Perhaps you want data-cost and data-debt?

So if your input looks like this:

```
<input data-cost="" data-debt="" value="" type="checkbox" name="f_2[]" id="checkboxId" />
```

Then you can set the values in your javascript like this:

```
var value1="some value";
var value2="another value";
$('#checkboxId').data('cost', value1);
$('#checkboxId').data('debt', value2);
```

I don't believe having an attribute named simply "debt" as you have it above is valid.

Comment: I am aware of that, I am using them for a another jquery function on the page. The page is a debt elimination worksheet for credit counselors. The page has several calculating functions. I did not write all of it, I am just a novice :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way (setTimeout was useless) :

```
$(function () {
    $('#account_balance1').on('keyup blur paste', function () {
        var self = this;
        var nextCheckbox = $(self).next("input[type='checkbox']");
        var str = $(self).val();
        $("#viewer").text(str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
        nextCheckbox.data({
            cost: str,
            debt: str
        });
        /*
        You won't be able to see changes if you inspect element,
        so just check in console
        */
        console.log(nextCheckbox.data());

});
```

});

And your html markup must be slightly modified :

```
<!--This where I get the value from -->
<input type="text" class="balance" id="account_balance1" name="cardb" value="" />

<!--the first 2 elements are where I need the values to go -->
<input data-cost="" data-debt="" value="" type="checkbox" name="f_2[]" />

<!--I added the viewer to check if everything works properly -->
<div id="viewer"></div>
```

Comment: Actually I don't know if you misread question, but I don't need viewer anymore. But changing the element's name is fine.

Comment: Oh, i thought you wanted your script to work both with viewer and checkbox.

Comment: Thats ok, thanks for your help, I was just letting you know. I wrote "instead of the `<div id="viewer">`" on the question. I did not know what I was suppose to do when I started this, so I am just changing where the data goes.

Comment: Yep, but you wrote too "I need to modify it to **also** go into two different form elements" :p

Comment: Yep you're right, I need to proofread better, sorry bout that. I am trying it out now to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Just curious, how come you are at 233 points, didn't they give you a free 100 points when you hit 200? I am trying to understand their system

Comment: Uh ? No free points on StackOverflow :) You maybe gained a bounty ?